# Side bar or Navigation Drawer in ios APP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation-drawer, sidebar

I've an application and in that I need a side bar just like navigation drawer in android. I've seen several third parties but it seems they are not useful for me. Because I've more than 5 ViewControllers and in each ViewController I need the same Sidebar. How can I do it. And i'm a beginner please help.

Comment: so what...you can use that 3rd party libraries in more than one view controllers ..its not for one controller

Comment: one?? check all...https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=drawer

Comment: Which is easy to implement and will be useful for five view controllers

Comment: On Cocoa Controls You can find so many demos...

Comment: Code4app is also providing good examples.

Comment: If you are using objective c you can you SWRevealViewController. There's an easy tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SUV1YY2yxQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a Good number of Third Parties available at [cocoacontrols.com](https://cocoacontrols.com) and at [github.com](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=navigation%20drawer%20iOS&type=).

goto [cocoacontrols.com](https://cocoacontrols.com) and type navigation menu or drawer on search bar you will find a lot of answers. Demos are also given in github.

Example links:

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

https://github.com/JVillella/JVFloatingDrawer

https://github.com/dogo/AKSideMenu

download the zip file and include it in your project and follow the instructions.

But somehow Third party is third party. If you wanna avoid third parties, try popover menus for the same purpose.

Comment: MMDrawerController is ugly, it doesn't look like Android nav drawer and it expands form bottom bar

Comment: and others don't look like good too

Answer (score 5):

try these MMDrawerController its very easy to understand and implement,it offers lots of customization..

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries that help you accomplish this; a simple Google search for "ios navigation drawer library" will give you some examples.  However, please note that this is considered [poor UI design](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/24/before-the-hamburger-button-kills-you/) these days.

However, if you still want to accomplish this, and you are worried about sharing amongst view controllers, you could use a top-level UINavigationController to hold your child view controllers.  Or you could [make your own container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) where you swap out the child view controllers but still show the navigation drawer button somewhere.